# FLOCSSでいうutilityについて

Tags: css

FLOCSSでいうutilityは便利なので、たくさん使いたくなってしまいますが、
制作時は良くても、クラス名がたくさんになってしまうと、
CSSがまとまっておらず管理がしにくいという説もあります。

どのような制限をつけて使っていますか？
好き放題使っても問題ないのでしょうか？

例

```
/* Bottom margin */
.u-mb-0{
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.u-mb-0dot1rem{
    margin-bottom: .1rem !important;
}

.u-mb-0dot2rem{
    margin-bottom: .2rem !important;
}

.u-mb-0dot3rem{
    margin-bottom: .3rem !important;
}
```

またcompornentはそれ自体にwidthやmarginなどはつけないようですが、
するとすべてutilityで指定するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component間のマージン調整は、Projectレイヤーを付与し、都度上書きを行っていくのが良いです。
あまりutilityのみでのレイアウト調整はおすすめしません。
付与classが膨大になる上、上書きが困難になるので。

utilityの設計自体は自由ですが、class命名にはEmmetの省略記法を用いると良いかもしれませんね。
また、`margin`などに関しては単位を統一することで`0dot3rem`を`dot3`にしたりできますね。

Projectレイヤーによるスタイル調整は下記が参考になるかと
[Projectレイヤーを使いこなす！ – FLOCSSで始めるCSS設計](https://www.to-r.net/media/floccs-04/)

FLOCSSを使用している参考サイトとしてはこのサイトが参考になるかもしれません。
（おそらく、FLOCSSの提唱者の谷氏による設計が行われたものかと）

http://tsukuruba.com/careers/

Comment: ありがとうごさいますすごい会社で働かれているのですね。

Comment: 下記を見せてもらいました。
c-avatarにはOOCSSでいうスキンだけを記載し、ストラクチャはp-author__avatar-btnに記載し、マルチクラスにするということでよいでしょうか？
つまり、c-avatarには他のサイトでこのコンポーネントを再利用する際に、まず間違いなく変更することがないcssのみ記載し、
その他をp-に記載するということですね。


<div class="p-author__avatar c-avatar">

.c-avatar {
 
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.p-author__avatar-btn{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-right: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

Comment: その通りです。マルチクラスという考え方であっています。
もし、`.c-`にて定義したスタイルが変更が必要な場合は`.p-`を与える際に上書き、打ち消しても構いませんので、`.c-`の設計の際にはあまり深く考えすぎなくてもよいでしょう。

Comment: c-avatarにはOOCSSでいうスキンだけを記載し、ストラクチャはp-author__avatar-btnに記載し、‌​マルチクラスにするということでよいのですね。
ありがとうごさいます。そのあたりが、谷氏のグリーン本になく大変困っていました。

c-avatarにはOOCSSでいうスキンだけを記載し、ストラクチャはp-は分けるのがあいまいで難しいので最悪c-にmargin、paddingなど絶対に違う部分だけ記載し、
その他はp-で上書きでも問題ないのですね。

Comment: ＞＞＞utilityの設計自体は自由ですが、class命名にはEmmetの省略記法を用いると良いかもしれませんね。
また、marginなどに関しては単位を統一することで0dot3remをdot3にしたりできますね。

Comment: おっしゃる通り上記のクラス名にも困っています。

Comment: .u-fontsize-em-10per {
    font-size: .１em;
}　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　上記のようにするといいかとも思ったのですが

Comment: そうすると、1%がある場合クラス名がかぶってしまいます。

Comment: エスケープシーケンスを使うと今度はサブライム

Comment: のgotocssが使えなくなりました。ここはエンターを

Comment: 押すと勝手に投稿されてしまうのですね。コメントだらけになってすいません。

Comment: [https://github.com/hiloki/flocss](https://github.com/hiloki/flocss)
谷氏のGithub上のドキュメントに少し近いものは書いていますが、具体例は少ないかと思います。私も最初の頃はかなり試行錯誤しました。

`.u-`クラスについては、clearfixなど最低限にするのが良いかと思います。なるべく`.c-`や`.p-`で解決する前提で設計することが望ましいです。

改行については`shift + enter`で行えますよ！

Comment: ありがとうごさいます。
utilityはレンダリングの速度が

Comment: 若干下がるので、ドバーと記載するのはやめたほうがいいのですね。

Comment: あと、レイアウト系のスタイルを`.u-`でやるとレスポンシブで困りますね。

Comment: 私はu-margin-res-smallとやってしまっていますが、

Comment: デザイナーやクライアントさんが細かい人だと確かにむりですね。
.u-mb-0dot2rem{
 margin-bottom: .2rem !important;
}
というクラス名も何とかしないといけないので

Comment: 再質問させてもらいます。もしよかったら見てください。