# flocssのプレフィックスについて

Tags: css

flocssのプレフィックスについて
下記のような場合どのフォルダにあるかわかるようにするためにc-やp-を付けるべきでしょうか？
ただそうすると

```
.is-fadeout {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}

.is-fadein {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
```

.c-is-fadein
となってプレフィックスが二つになってしまいます。
どうしていますか？

Comment: 第三者が上から読んで意味がとりやすい質問になるようお願いします。ヘルプセンターの[「良い質問をするには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)をよくお読みください。

Comment: `c-`や`p-`は具体的にどういう意味を表しているのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu https://github.com/hiloki/flocss#objectのプレフィックス

Comment: 詳しくないのですが、class付けのときに `class="c-image is-fadeout"` のようにして、`.c-image.is-fadeout { ... }` とするのでは解決できないのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。.c-image.is-fadeout { ... } としても結局is-fadeoutはどこにあるのだろうとなってしまいますよね
必ずその手前にある.c-image.と同じ場所にあるというルールでもあればいいですがそのようなルールを聞いたことがありません

Comment: ステートパターンの「場所」というのがよくわからないのですが、具体的にどういう状況になると困るのか教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: プレフィックスはどこにあるのかを示すためにつけるのですがisだとどのフォルダにあるかわからないですよね

Comment: @temestack 少し調べてみましたが、`is-`プレフィクスは`c-`や`p-`と違って状態を表すためのプレフィクスなので、どのフォルダにあるかは関係ないんじゃないかと思いました。FLOCSSのルールにも「`.is-***`そのものにルールを持たせるのは禁止します」とあり、これを守ろうとすると場所とは関係なくなる気がします。たとえばこの記事のサンプルコードのような感じです。 https://www.tam-tam.co.jp/tipsnote/html_css/post10205.html

Comment: is自体はおっしゃる通り状態を表すものです。
ただこれだけしかつけられないのであれば致し方ないですが、これですとcompornentなのかprojectの中にあるのかわかりませんよね。よってis-c-のようにすることは許されるのかなと思った次第です。

Answer (score 1):

[FLOCSSのルール](https://github.com/hiloki/flocss)に厳密にしたがうと、そもそもご質問にあるようなスタイル付けの仕方は不正です。というのも`is-`プレフィックスのついているクラスがルールを持つことは禁止されているからです。これは`.is-***`そのものの持つルールが、他のモジュールのModifierのスタイルを汚染してしまうのを防ぐためです。

そこでFLOCSSでは、ObjectとStateを分離して別々のクラスを付けます。FLOCSSの規約からサンプルコードを引用すると、次のような感じです。

```
<button class="c-button is-active">Save</button>
```

```
.c-button { ... }
.c-button.is-active { ... }
```

複数のObjectに同じStateがつく場合は、それぞれに対してスタイルをつけるべきなのでしょう。たとえばQiitaの[「FLOCSSを使ってCSSファイルを20,000行から9,000行にした話」](http://qiita.com/Atsss/items/4f9d98fb1d0546539c09)で紹介されているサイトのCSSではそうなっています。あるいは[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/29790/19110)で挙げられているサイトのCSSでもそうなっています。[後者のサイトのCSS](http://tsukuruba.com/tsukuruba2015/wp-content/themes/tsukuruba2016/css/2016.css)だと、

```
.p-globalNavHorizontal__subnav.is-expanded.is-active { ... }
```

というものさえありますね。